# Samsung phone has a broken power button, no physical home button and no bixby button. How can I power it up?

Tags: samsung, power-on, water-damage

I have a Samsung A20 (A205W) with a broken power button (probably water damage), the only other physical buttons are the volume buttons. How can I power it up?

Thanks

Comment: Volume Down + usb cable, then flash something and wait for auto reboot. Be warned this might brick in case power button is short-circuited (and interrupt flashing)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up pressing up and down button then plugging it in and it worked